# Ionic ng-if comparando valores

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou a obter dados de uma [API](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/) e pretendo fazer uma verificação se percent_change_1h é menor que 0, e se assim for apresenta uma cor de texto diferente.

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label ng-if="top.percent_change_1h < 0" style="color: #b21a91;">
        <b>1H: </b>{{top.percent_change_1h}}
      </ion-label>
      <ion-label ng-if="top.percent_change_1h > 0">
        <b>1H: </b>{{top.percent_change_1h}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Como poderei fazer este processo de comparação, para caso seja menor que 0 apresentar uma cor, e se for maior ou igual a zero apresentar outra?

Comment: Mas qual o problema? Seu código não esta funcionando? Qual parte não funciona? Para mim, aparentemente esta correto.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar [ng-class](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-class.asp)!

Basicamente, ele funciona da seguinte forma:
Você passa uma condição para ele, e se essa condição for verdadeira, ele aplica tal classe, se não, aplica outra.
Então o que você deve fazer é:

1. Definir a expressão condicional ("se X for menor que 2");
2. Criar a classe de condição verdadeira;
3. Criar a classe de condição falsa;
4. Relacionar isso tudo no ng-class do elemento que vai pintar.

Exemplo: (Vai pintar o FUNDO do ion-label, não as letras)

```css
.maiorQueZero {
  background-color: #006600;
}
.menorQueZero {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label ng-class="top.percent_change_1h > 0? 'maiorQueZero' : 'menorQueZero' ">
      
      <!-- Se top.percent_change_1h for maior que 0, aplica a classe 'maiorQueZero', se não (:) aplica o menorQueZero-->
      
        <b>1H: </b>{{top.percent_change_1h}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: Já consegui solucionar o meu problema, não estava a par que na versão do angular 2+ o ng-if tinha passado a *ngIf

Comment: Ah sim, houve essa mudança mesmo. As 2 formas ficam corretas, porém, acredito que utilizando o ng-class o código fica mais limpo.